# UITableView cell Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am using a custom cell for my table view. I have a switch in my cell. When I toggle the switch for certain cells, my switch vanishes from random cells. This only happens if I give a target action to my switch. When I comment the addTarget code, the table view works fine.  Can any one help please?

The snap shot of the custom cell is:[image]

The code for my CellForRowAtIndexPath is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = placesTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ApproveCustomCell
    cell.placeType.text = places[indexPath.row].type
    cell.placeName.text = places[indexPath.row].name
    cell.placePhone.text = places[indexPath.row].phone
    cell.placeWebsite.text = places[indexPath.row].website
    cell.placeAddress.text = places[indexPath.row].address

    cell.switchOutlet.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.switchOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.approveRejectPlace(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    if places[indexPath.row].status! == "Approved" {
        cell.switchOutlet.on = true
    }else {
        cell.switchOutlet.on = false
    }

    return cell

}
```

## UPDATE

This is my Approve/reject method:

```
func approveRejectPlace(sender: UISwitch!){

    var url = "\(baseUrl)\(approveRejectUrl)"
    if sender.on == true {
            url += ("Approved/\(places[sender.tag].id))")
    }else {
        url += ("Rejected/\(places[sender.tag].id)")
    }

print(self.places[sender.tag].name)

    let parameters = ["key" : encryptedKey , "salt" : encryptedSalt]
    self.view.lock()
    dataProvider.hitWebservice(url, parameters: parameters) { (jsonArray) in

        self.view.unlock()

        if let results = jsonArray[0] as? NSDictionary {

            if let result = results.objectForKey("result") as? Bool {

                if result {

                    if sender.on {
                        self.places[sender.tag].status = "Approved"
                    }else {
                        self.places[sender.tag].status = "Rejected"
                    }

//                        self.placesTableView.reloadData()

                }else {

                    invokeAlertMethod("Error", msgBody: "Failed to approve the place", delegate: self)
                    sender.on = false
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you post `approveRejectPlace` method ?

Comment: Yes, sure I have added it to the question

Comment: Change the - forControlEvents: .ValueChanged

Comment: I figured out the issue. But donot know the reason for it. Actually I have a UIView extension to lock/unlock a view. It places an activity indicator over the view. This was causing the issue. But I could not find why is this causing the issue. I use this same extension for every project.

Comment: Maybe it is having issue because of cell reusability because table view keep copying same cells after a specific pattern

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. I got the reason behind the issue also. Actually the unlock extension removes the view with tag = 10. So all the switches with tag =10 were removed.